# Distance finder not printing text

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make this sign that, when you step close enough, shows a GUI.

To test it, I made it `print("It works!")` but It won't print anything.

LocalScript:

```
local Players = game:GetService('Players')
local LocalPlayer = Players.LocalPlayer

for _,Player in next, Players:GetChildren() do
    local character = Player.Character
    if character and character.Parent and Player ~= LocalPlayer then
        local Magnitude = (LocalPlayer.Character.HumanoidRootPart.Position - character.HumanoidRootPart.Position).magnitude
        
    end
end
while true do
    if Magnitude < 10 then
        print("It's working!")
    end
end
```

Comment: Note: It is a localScript, and in the block itself.

Comment: Localscripts can't be used on the server. They must be used on the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have put a LocalScript into a Part in the Workspace. If you check [the LocalScript docs](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/LocalScript), you'll see that ...

> a LocalScript will only run Lua code if it is a descendant of one of the following objects:
>
> - A Player’s Backpack, such as a child of a Tool
> - A Player’s character model
> - A Player’s PlayerGui
> - A Player’s PlayerScripts.
> - The ReplicatedFirst service

So to fix your issue, you either need to

- A) convert your code to a Script and access the Player objects through the Players service. or
- B) move the LocalScript to a place where it will start executing and update the code accordingly.

If you go the route of Option B, follow these steps :

First, move the LocalScript into StarterPlayer > StarterCharacterScripts. This will cause the script to execute when the player's character spawns into the world.

Then, update the code so that it can find the block and show the distance to the player.

```
local localPlayer = game.Players.LocalPlayer

-- locate the sign in the world
-- local signGui = game.Workspace:WaitForChild("Part"):WaitForChild("UI")

-- set the range where the sign should appear
local DISTANCE_TO_SHOW_SIGN = 10 -- studs

-- every game tick, calculate the distance between the part and the character
game.RunService.Heartbeat:Connect(function()
    -- escape if the player's character doesn't exist
    if not localPlayer.Character then
        return
    end

    -- calculate the distance to each of the players
    -- if two players are close enough to each other, show the sign
    local shouldShowSign = false
    local myPosition = localPlayer.Character.HumanoidRootPart.Position

    for _, otherPlayer in ipairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
        if (otherPlayer ~= localPlayer) and (otherPlayer.Character) then
            local theirPosition = otherPlayer.Character.HumanoidRootPart.Position
            local distBetween = (myPosition - theirPosition)
            
            -- optimization : when calculating distance, try to avoid using square roots
            -- use pythagorean theorem : dist = sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)
            -- instead, use dist^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2
            if (distBetween * distBetween) < (DISTANCE_TO_SHOW_SIGN ^ 2) then
                shouldShowSign = true
                break
            end
        end
    end

    -- show the sign if two players are close enough together
    if shouldShowSign then
        print("it's working")
    end
    -- optimization : only set the visibility when it changes
    -- if signGui.Visible ~= shouldShowSign then
    --    signGui.Visible = shouldShowSign
    -- end
end)
```

Comment: Thanks, that really helps now. The other answer seemed to be on the right track, but didn’t actually get it right.

Comment: Since these distance checks are happening every tick, I've modified the code to improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has 3 main issues
1: Its a regular script, not a localscript
2: Your while true do loop will timeout when the server starts
3: Magnitude is only defined when doing for i,v

Try this code in a localscript instead

```lua
local Players = game:GetService('Players')
local LocalPlayer = Players.LocalPlayer
local Magnitude
while true do
    wait()
    for _,Player in next, Players:GetChildren() do
    local character = Player.Character
    if character and character.Parent and Player ~= LocalPlayer then
        Magnitude = (LocalPlayer.Character.HumanoidRootPart.Position - character.HumanoidRootPart.Position).magnitude
        
    end
end

if Magnitude ~= nil then
    if Magnitude < 10 then
        print("It's working!")
    end
end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the improved answer. If this was the first answer I got, I would have probably accepted it but due to the other one coming first and me using it, I don’t really want to unnacept it.

Comment: Okay. That is fine.

Comment: This updated answer still has problems. The original code in the question is already a LocalScript, and this code will still not execute, as the location of the LocalScript is still in a Part in the Workspace. Next,  you have closed the while loop after the magnitude calculation, so it is never used. And finally, you have a syntax error caused by too many 'end' statements.

Comment: You need to put the script in StarterPlayerScripts.